# How to get a substring of column rows within a table with a regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, substring

I am trying to condense a description column to only display the vital information in Postgresql. I have come up with this:

```
select description, substring(description from '.{0,5}base.{0,5}') as minidesc
from cbp.export_final
where product_code in ('LU016', 'LU017', 'LU018', 'LU019', 'LU020')
limit 1000;
```

However, nothing is extracted with the substring. Can anyone help explain why this is not working?

Comment: Please show us examples of the content of `description` along with the expected result.

Comment: `
1 PACKAGE(S) OF (FLEXITANK) BASE OIL PALE 2000 (HARMONIZED CODE: 270799)
` is an example of a typical description. 
I am trying to extract "base" out of it with some of the outer edge characters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just need to make your search case-insensitive. For this, you can prefix with option `i`(nsensitive):

```
substring(description from '(?i).{0,5}base.{0,5}') as minidesc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bb367eda1e802ab64baa038338690b8d)**:

```
with export_final as (
    select 
        '1 PACKAGE(S) OF (FLEXITANK) BASE OIL PALE 2000 (HARMONIZED CODE: 270799)' description,
        'LU016' product_code
)
select description, substring(description from '(?i).{0,5}base.{0,5}') as minidesc
from export_final
where product_code in ('LU016', 'LU017', 'LU018', 'LU019', 'LU020')
```

```
description                                                              | minidesc      
:----------------------------------------------------------------------- | :-------------
1 PACKAGE(S) OF (FLEXITANK) BASE OIL PALE 2000 (HARMONIZED CODE: 270799) | ANK) BASE OIL
```

---

You might also want to consider the following regexp, which gives you the *word* after and before `'base'` - a word being defined as alphanumeric characters plus the underscore character (`_`):

```
(?i)\w+\W+base\W+\w+
```

For your sample data, this produces:

```
FLEXITANK) BASE OIL
```